# Inexpensive API for facilitating money transactions between users

Tags: online-payment

I'm designing an app, which I'd like to facilitate transactions between users. 
I'm looking at a few options but I'm not sure they're a good Idea

There's [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/us/connect/pricing).
Which pretty much does what I want, but they're expensive.  I'm the sole developer of this app and I'm funding this with my own capitol.

I'm also looking at [Ethereum's Smart Contracts](https://www.ethereum.org/)
But this will limit my users, and cause a problem in the future, because it will cause an issue when A user pays with ethereum and another user only accepts ACH.

I would like a simple ACH Solution, I don't mind if it takes a few days for the funds to clear,  but I would prefer if the payment in the beginning is only done by taking a percentage off of the transaction occuring.

Comment: Stripe is probably the way to go. Why do you think it is expensive? A similar (but I don't think cheaper) option is https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/android/v1

Comment: @Yisroel I will have to pay 2 dollars for every active user each month plus 25 cents fee and a percentage on each transaction. I was aiming to make a dollar off of a user per transaction it seems pricey I’ll have to change all of my pricing plans etc

Comment: Oh, I missed the point that the payments are between the users, and not just paid out to you :-(

Comment: Yeah :/ regular stripe looks great but I can’t use it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Stripe Connect** is actually the better-known brand for this, but as you say it can get expansive for your use-case.

Other than that are not many good options. The best one I could find is the [**Dwolla Facilitate**](https://www.dwolla.com/platform?b=blog) option, which they describe as:

> Provide the interface that allows your users to send funds to each other via Dwolla

See technical details here https://www.dwolla.com/updates/which-payment-apis-could-i-use-to-build-a-peer-to-peer-money-transfer-product/

Comment: For anyone else whose come to see this.  Dwolla looks promising, However, they're terrible with customer relations.    I've been trying to obtain a production license, they won't even respond with what the requirements are to obtain one